# Make home screen icons round again, after Huawei update

Tags: huawei, home-screen-shortcuts, app-icons, emui

Yesterday I installed a suggested update on my Huawei nova3i, to EMUI version 9.1.0

There is one change which I don't like.  Many apps installed from the app store used to have round icons, but now they have square icons.

See in this before and after, how the 'Calm', 'MeeWee' and 'Vimeo' icons have changed shape:

[image]     [image]

(We can also see that the icons grew a little bit larger, which I don't really find appealing either.)

**Is it possible to restore the old look, with smaller round icons for apps from the App Store?**

(I am willing to install a theme if I have to, but I don't really want the default icons, wallpapers and text to change!)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the device somehow lost my theme, and this ugly look is the fallback "no theme found" behaviour.

Anyway, I downloaded the "Legend" theme from [this website](https://www.themefoxx.com/2018/09/huawei-mate-20-themes.html), and used [these instructions](https://uk.community.huawei.com/software-40/emui-9-1-iconography-would-like-round-icons-without-edge-5648) to apply it.

After I applied that theme (although I think any theme would do), I got a reasonable compromise: smaller icons and rounded-square borders.  This is certainly improvement.

[image]

Now I just need to reset the font and wallpaper, which I can do.

Still, if anyone knows how to get the really round icons again, I would like that.